# Webflux CORS No Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: java, cors, spring-webflux

I've made a project using webflux and i'm new to this.
I'm trying to implement the configuration of CORS request but I'm getting this exception:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at '<url of my server>' from origin 'http://localhost:8100/' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

My configuration is:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
public class CorsGlobalConfiguration implements WebFluxConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry corsRegistry) {
        corsRegistry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS")
                .allowedHeaders("User-Agent,Referer,Origin,Host,Connection,Access-Control-Request-Method," +
                        "Access-Control-Request-Headers,Cache-Control,Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept," +
                        "Accept-Encoding,Accept-Language, Authorization")
                .maxAge(3600);
    }
}
```

PS: I've read that the best way to handle CORS is through the use of a filter? Is it true?

This configuration is pretty similar to the non - reactive webflux project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The `allowedMethods` method](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/e2832ea596908322d35f2ed3aceb300368373d8a/spring-webflux/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/reactive/config/CorsRegistration.java#L83) is a variadic method and expects method names to be specified one at a time, not all of them separated by commas in a single string argument. Instead of

```java
allowedMethods("GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS")
```

you should write

```java
allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "DELETE", "PUT", "OPTIONS")
```

(Incidentally, contrary to popular belief, `OPTIONS` need not be listed here for CORS preflight to work.)

Similar remark about [the `allowHeaders` method](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/e2832ea596908322d35f2ed3aceb300368373d8a/spring-webflux/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/reactive/config/CorsRegistration.java#L97). This is an easy mistake to make, as Spring's CORS middleware performs no validation on user-specified method and header names.

---

This second point is unrelated to your issue but deserves to be mentioned: the Fetch standard lists all the following names as [forbidden request headers](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-request-header):

- Accept-Encoding
- Access-Control-Request-Method
- Access-Control-Request-Headers
- Connection
- Host
- Origin
- Referer

Therefore, you don't need to list any of them as allowed headers in your CORS configuration. You can simplify your call to `allowedHeaders` to

```java
allowedHeaders(
  "User-Agent",
  "Cache-Control",
  "X-Requested-With",
  "Content-Type",
  "Accept",
  "Accept-Encoding",
  "Accept-Language",
  "Authorization")
```