# How to disable cors on spring boot + spring security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

I have a spring boot rest application that can be accessed for example by https.dummy.cs. The  spring boot starter parent for my application is version 2.7.6 . I have added spring security dependency in my application to secure the endpoints. I have an angular app(deployed on http://localhost:4200) that is trying to connect to https://dev.dummy.cs and the following errors is displayed in my browser:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at https.dummy.cs from origin http://locahost has been blocked by cors policy
```

I have tried to  disable the cors policy in Spring as follows:

```
 @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        //@formatter:off
        httpSecurity
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .csrf().disable().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(sHandler);


        httpSecurity.cors().disable().
                
                antMatchers(ATT_WHITELIST).permitAll().
                anyRequest().authenticated();// whitelist Swagger UI resources
    

  ..
        httpSecurity.sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
```

I have also added the config cors as follows:

```
   @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowedOrigins("dev.dummy.cs,https://dev.dummy.cs");
        config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "DELETE", "PUT"));
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return source;
    }
```

Anybody can point me out what I am missing here please since i am getting the cors error?

Comment: The signature of that method is `public CorsRegistration allowedOrigins(String... origins)`. Each Web origin must be specified as a separate string. Besides, `dev.dummy.cs` is not a valid Web-origin value. Finally, the error message indicates that you need to allow `http://locahost:4200`, not `https://dev.dummy.cs`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webflux CORS No Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75022849/webflux-cors-no-access-control-allow-origin)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/cors/CorsConfiguration.html), `setAllowedOrigins` is defined as `public void setAllowedOrigins(@Nullable List<String> origins)`! You however didn't pass a `List<String>`, but a List inside of a String.
Therefore, please change
`config.setAllowedOrigins("dev.dummy.cs,https://dev.dummy.cs");` to `config.setAllowedOrigins("dev.dummy.cs", "https://dev.dummy.cs");`!

Furthermore, you deactivated your CORS config via `httpSecurity.cors().disable()`. In order for our previously defined CORS config to be activated, you must change it to `.and().cors()` inside your `httpSecurity`!

Comment: Attempts to allow `dev.dummy.cs` as a Web origin are doomed to failure, since this isn't a valid value for a Web origin. A well-designed CORS middleware would alert its users to such a configuration mistake. More about this on [my blog](https://jub0bs.com/posts/2023-02-08-fearless-cors/#5-validate-configuration-and-fail-fast).

Comment: Uh, you never stop learning, do you? Thanks for the note @jub0bs
Just noticed the wrong usage of the method for starters, as well as the deactivation of the config.. :) Thanks a lot for the addition as well as your blog.

Comment: CORS is more complicated than meets the eye. Thanks! 